# file_get_contents is not working for some url while trying to download file on server

Tags: php, file, curl, download, backend

I'm currently trying to feed my PHP an URL which I know leads to downloading a file.
Unfortunately, it seems like the place where the file is being taken from performs some kind of check that won't let me download the file

After reviewing some similar questions I got this:

```
fopen('cookies.txt', "w");
$parts = parse_url($url);
$host = $parts['host'];
$ch = curl_init();
$header = array('GET /1575051 HTTP/1.1',
    "Host: {$host}",
    'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
    'Connection:keep-alive'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
die(print_r($result)) ;
```

But unfortunately my Print_r still returns false. The url is this:
"https://www.yt-download.org/download/lGS9flfg8Vg/mp3/128/1625766046/246071ecaf23ce7f82782a54c1c44ea8343aa59de0723cee7a98bfd2c1865b59/0"

Anybody could spare a hand in understanding more about this?

Comment: Sites like that try very hard to protect from code such as yours. Anything that you try that succeeds will almost always fail in the future. At the end of the day, you have to mimic what a real browser is doing, and sometimes that means actually using a real browser. For instance, you can automate a headless Chrome install.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that but I'll give it a try. Thanks!